# How to make audio+video channel syncing (when doing splitting ) more user friendly?

Tags: imovie

I Have an audio track and the video track and want to split them both at the same point with cmd+b. I have to manually select Channels with the mouse in order for the split to be applied to the audio. But when I press cmd+b later the audio is not split and I have then reselect with the mouse, is this the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this the only way?

No, nor the friendly way.

**Using the Control button to maintain the current position.**

1. Place the line marker where you want to split the clips.
2. While holding the control button > click on the movie clip > select
   Split Clip.
3. While still holding the control button down > click on the audio track > select Split Clip.

That's it.